# PostgreSQL - Are BEFORE triggers more efficient then AFTER triggers?

Tags: performance, postgresql, triggers

I just read in the [PostgreSQL Documentation - Overview of Trigger behavior](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/trigger-definition.html), that BEFORE triggers are "more effecient" than AFTER triggers:

> If you have no specific reason to make
>   a trigger before or after, the before
>   case is more efficient, since the
>   information about the operation
>   doesn't have to be saved until end of
>   statement.

I do not understand if this is true or what it means for me. Can someone enlighten me? Is this just a homeopatic performance improvement?

Comment: +1 The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html) say `Row-level BEFORE triggers fire immediately before a particular row is operated on, while row-level AFTER triggers fire at the end of the statement...` which means the statement that fires the trigger can affect the performance you observe, depending on what your trigger does (i.e. if the statement just affects one row, then you shouldn't see much difference, but if it affects many rows then a `BEFORE` trigger could be more efficient...but as always, it's important to conduct your own test).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to `PostgreSQL`'s `MVCC` architecture, each operation increases the amount of data recorded in the system, even `DELETE`.

So if you just need to make checks of your input and rollback the transaction if the checks fail, you better do it before the input data are saved.

Comment: +1 This is more understandable to me. If only the error case is irrelevant, I won't care for this speed difference anymore.

Comment: DELETE doesn't increase the amount of data recorded in the system, it just doesn't release the space without a VACUUM. This is what autovacuum does, it cleans up dead tuples.

Comment: @Frank: it does increase the `WAL`, that's why I wrote "system" instead of "tablespace".

Comment: @Frank I had thought Quassnoi's point was that rolling back a transaction is more efficient the earlier you do it as MVCC means until the commit, the deleted row is still visible to everyone else. Which would surely have been a very good point.

Comment: What if i update records in some related table within the trigger. Is it still better to use BEFORE?

For example i have trigger on INSERT and want to increment counter in my own stats table. Does BEFORE trigger still efficient and suitable?

Answer (score 2):

For an update trigger, I found no measurable difference on my system:

with 'before' trigger:

```
begin;

create function f() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin 
  new.time_of_day:=old.time_of_day+'1d'::interval; 
  return new; 
end;$$;

create table t(time_of_day timestamp);

insert into t(time_of_day)
select timeofday()::timestamp from generate_series(1,100000);

update t set time_of_day = timeofday()::timestamp;

select max(time_of_day)-min(time_of_day) from t;

    ?column?
-----------------
 00:00:47

create trigger trig before insert on t for each row execute procedure f();

update t set time_of_day = timeofday()::timestamp;

select max(time_of_day)-min(time_of_day) from t;

    ?column?
-----------------
 00:00:47.432173

rollback;
```

with 'after' trigger:

```
create function f() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin 
  new.time_of_day:=old.time_of_day+'1d'::interval; 
  return new; 
end;$$;

create table t(time_of_day timestamp);

insert into t(time_of_day)
select timeofday()::timestamp from generate_series(1,100000);

update t set time_of_day = timeofday()::timestamp;

select max(time_of_day)-min(time_of_day) from t;

    ?column?
-----------------
 00:00:48.566558

create trigger trig after insert on t for each row execute procedure f();

update t set time_of_day = timeofday()::timestamp;

select max(time_of_day)-min(time_of_day) from t;

    ?column?
-----------------
 00:00:48.922441
```

But for some reason I get a very noticeable *degradation* with a 'before' *insert* trigger as compared to an 'after' insert trigger or a control

Comment: +1 Thanks for trying it out. But don't your results really show that AFTER is slower?

Comment: @Daniel each test is compared against a control. The margin of difference between the (identical) controls is far higher than the difference between the control and the `update` with a the trigger in each case

Comment: While Postgres fires `BEFORE` triggers between rows, it doesn't start firing `AFTER` triggers until the end of the statement. In other words, the `AFTER` triggers all fall outside your `time_of_day` range. You're better off just using psql's `\timing`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you are going to prove it one way or another is to test it and see if it matters for what you are doing.

Thinking logically at the high level... if you are taking an extra step to retain more information vs not taking the extra step of course one is more work than the other.  Just as walking one extra step is more work even though it may not take you a noticeable time difference. For example to walk 10 feet with 10 steps vs 11 steps.